# Javascript: how to find factor pairs from any given integer

Tags: javascript

I need find the number of factor pairs from any given number. (See an example of the kind of thing [here](http://mathsolutions.50webs.com/factorpairs.html). The difference is that I need to know how many pairs there are, not just the pairs themselves.) I really have no idea how to start this and I was hoping that someone would be able to assist me.

Comment: Have you searched for "big integer" packages in NPM that can do this sort of thing? Raw JavaScript integers don't get very large (up to only `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`) so such operations are not usually needed on plain numbers.

Comment: This should be trivial from the source code you linked. Instead of outputting each pair, increment a variable each time the linked code would output a pair, then output that at the end of `doit()`

Answer (score 1):

You already had the answer without knowing it,

from the source of [the page you mentionned](http://mathsolutions.50webs.com/factorpairs.html):

```
function doit(){
    a=document.factors.num.value;    //number to be evaluated
    checker=Math.sqrt(a);    //maximum divisor
    output="";

    for (x=1; x<=checker; x++)
    {
        c=a/x;
        d=Math.floor(c);
        // compare integer answer and division answer
        if(c==d){
        output = output + "factor pair = " +  c +  "," +  x  + "\n";
        }
    }
 document.factors.worksp.value=output;
}
```

It's even well enough commented to understand the solution.
There is one pair for each time we go into the if(c==d) case, so the job is pretty much done from that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea how to do it:

```
var anyNumber = 6;
var count = 0;
var number1 = 0;
var number2 = anyNumber;
for (var i = 1; i < anyNumber; i++){
    if (anyNumber % i === 0){
        number1 = i;
      number2 = anyNumber / i;
    if (number2 >= number1){
      count++
    } else {
        break;
    }
  }
}
alert(count);
```

If you don'w want have result of unique pairs, so just ignore:

```
if (number2 >= number1)
```

You can change anyNumber to number which you want. The code above, loops until you will not reach the point when number2 will be smaller then number1 (unique pairs).